# Enterprise Architect component traceability

Tags: documentation, enterprise-architect

I'm trying to produce a traceability matrix such as this:

```
Interface Alias | Interface | From Component | To Component | Info Passed | Fn
INT.3.7         | Cord      | Solar Panel    | Battery      | Electricity | Fn1.2
```

How can I report these relationships?  I've built a component diagram and tried 
using an exposed interfaces and assemblies like this:

[image]

The Model Report shows the information in a somewhat related fashion, but trying to customize the document template fails to produce the type of matrix I'm seeking.

Is this even possible with EA?  It's my understanding that CORE by Vitech does this out of the box.

Comment: It should be possible using EA's documentation. Can't answer concrete since I'm documenting using the API where you can do anything.

Comment: you shouldn't be using an assembly connetor between two interfaces to my knowledge. You should be using dependency from the required interface to the provided interface, or not use the interfaces at all

Comment: where are you storing the "Interface" data the "info Passed" data and the "Fn" data?

Comment: @Hue I'd also recommend using a simple dependency. The assembly connector should be used for concepts where no concrete interface is defined so far. Though, I guess it's not "wrong" per se from the UML specs.

Comment: Thanks Thomas.  @Thomas RE: API, what would you recommend in getting started?  The goal of this school project is to build the traceability table so I'm open to anything at this point.  I'd prefer not to have to manually build the table in Excel (~150 req's, ~50 fn's, ~ 40 components).

Comment: Thanks, Hue.  @Hue RE: storing interface/info passed/fn data is the exposed interface name, assembly name, and functions (blocks - not shown).

Comment: Thanks, Thomas.  @Thomas RE: simple dependency; would this meet the need to represent in a table what's being passed between two components and via what method (e.g. electricity from component a->b over a wire)?

Comment: Technically there is no difference. Both are connectors and you would see them in, say, the relationship matrix and in a generated document. It's a style question.

Comment: from my knowledge, the assembly connector is used to represent an actuality (what is actually happening, right now) and the dependency is used to represent the concept that this interface depends on this interface. I'm no UML Expert, so I could be wrong

Comment: Scott, which Edition of EA are you using? I'm guessing Desktop?

Comment: Seems like you need to export this to CSV. However you won't be able to get the functions with the simple csv export of EA, so you will need to write a script. Unless you have access to the Office integration MDG, which has more advanced Excel export

Comment: @Hue- I'm using Ultimate Edition.  Thanks for the tip RE: MDG - I'll check it out!

Comment: @ThomasKilian - for the sake of simplicity, I went the route of using an Information Flow connector between the two components and simply described what was being passed as the name of the IF connection.  I found it very difficult to determine multiple level of relationships using Assemblies, ports, and such.  Thanks for the SQL tips!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a fairly simple SQL search and export the result of that search to CSV (which is a standard feature in EA).

More info on writing SQL searches and some example can be found here:

- [Sparx help](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/model_navigation/creating_filters.html)
- [My website](https://bellekens.com/?s=sql)

**Edit** As an example you can paste the following SQL into the SQL search window:

```
select Connector_ID, Direction, Connector_Type, t_object.Name, so.name, eo.name
from t_connector, t_object, t_object so, t_object eo
where so.object_id = Start_Object_ID and eo.object_id = End_Object_ID
```

and extend it to fit your needs. The result of the search can be copy/pasted.

Comment: That seems the way to go. It would help the OP if you attach a sample SQL to export connectors, so he has a starting point.

Comment: Thanks, @ThomasKilian and Geert.  I reviewed the Sparx help and your site but not finding anything that can show connection relationships and information flows between components.  I also tried the MDG but it did not report on relationships either.  Are either of you aware of a plug-in/add-on or a consultant that could help create such a table?

Comment: Well, we could both provide help as consultants :-) However, the information flow topic has been discussed and Helmut Ortmann (also a consultant) has provided some SQL which you can find in my Inside book. I'll have a look if I can find the forum reference. P.S. http://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,37742.msg235766.html#msg235766